# x86 program to do an exponent

Tags: assembly, x86

For continuity, my last question was with adding numbers together with a function call: [Example x86-64 program](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248680/example-x86-64-program/248705#248705). In this one I've tried to apply the lessons pointed out in the previous answer (stack alignment, using `edx` instead of `rdx` where the results will fit). I've tried to comment inline with the code:

```
# We are going to calculate 7^2 + 2^4 = 49 + 16 = 65
# The exponent function supports whole numbers (long) >= 0

.section .data
base_1: .long   7
exp_1:  .long   2
base_2: .long   2
exp_2:  .long   4

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:


    # We will do the first function call, 7^2
    mov base_1(%rip),   %edi
    mov exp_1(%rip),    %esi
    call exp

    # needs to be 16-byte aligned before the next function call so do two pushes
    pushq $0
    pushq %rax

    # Now do the second function call
    mov base_2(%rip),   %edi
    mov exp_2(%rip),    %esi
    call exp

    # We have the return value in %eax so let's add this with our previous function's value
    popq %rdi
    
    add %eax,   %edi
    mov $60,    %eax
    syscall

exp:
    # Initialize %eax to 1
    mov $1,     %eax

exp_op:
    cmp $0,     %esi
    je exp_ret
    imul %edi,  %eax
    dec %esi
    jmp exp_op

exp_ret:
    ret
```

I have a few specific questions about the code:

- Is doing a raw `push`/`pop` common? Or is the convention always to do `push rbp` `mov rsp rbp`...`pop rbp`. Why is one method preferred over the other?
- What if I wanted to store the result of the first calculation in a register: are there any registers that are guaranteed to be preserved between function calls? Or is this why the `push...pop` method is used so much?
- Finally, does my `exp` seem ok? It feels a bit odd having three labels in what amounts to one function. How could that be improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert, but what the heck, here's a review comment:

```
# needs to be 16-byte aligned before the next function call so do two pushes
pushq $0
pushq %rax
```

This comment is good, but I would rephrase it. Two eight-byte pushes makes 16 bytes and doesn't change the stack alignment. Therefore I infer that *one* of these pushes is *significant* and the other one is *insignificant* — but your comment doesn't tell me which is which! So you might say instead

```
# one extra push to preserve 16-byte stack alignment
pushq $0

# push the result of `exp`
pushq %rax
```

You could make the generated code smaller by eliminating the insignificant constant `$0`:

```
# push the result of `exp`, plus one extra push to preserve 16-byte stack alignment
pushq %rax
pushq %rax
```

Now the reader doesn't even need to figure out which push is the significant one, because both pushes do the same thing!

---

But why is preserving 16-byte alignment on calls important? That's not a requirement of the *machine*. You seem to be trying to follow some specific *ABI*, like maybe for interoperability with C or C++. Your external documentation should be clearer about what ABI you're trying to follow.

And then, if you *are* trying to interoperate with C code, you could improve your code by indicating which of its labels are meant as external entrypoints and which ones are just internal local labels. It seems like you intend `exp` to be called from other code — it's an entrypoint — but e.g. `exp_op` is not callable, and `exp_ret` is technically callable but just acts as a no-op. You might mark them somehow as "local implementation details, not for external consumption."

Yeah, you technically already do this by exporting `.globl _start` and not `.globl exp` — but there's still a big difference between the callable function `exp` and the local label `exp_op` which is not reflected in your naming scheme. If I were doing this, I'd add `.globl exp` and I'd rename `exp_op, exp_ret` to something like `Lexp1, Lexp2` or `L1_looptop, L2_loopend`.